# QTableWidgetItem.itemAt(pos) always returns 0 on contextMenu request

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget

I have a slot which creates a context menu given a point.  However, no matter which method I use to return the position from the point, table->itemAt(pos) always returns 0.  Is there any way to print out the tables row/columns positions so I can reverse engineer some offsets?

I tried every permutation possible and 'no item' is always executed....

```
void test::newContextMenu(const QPoint& point)
{
QPoint pos = table_->viewport()->mapFromGlobal(point); //also tried
//table_->mapFromGlobal(point), table_>viewport()->mapToGlobal(point)
//table_->mapToGlobal(point), and QCursor::pos()

QAction* action tableMenu_->exec(pos);
if(action == XX)
{
QTableWidgetItem* item = table_->itemAt(pos);
if(!item)
{
 ///no item
}
....
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your call to itemAt() should be using *point*, which is in coordinates local to your widget, not *pos* which is in global coordinates.

Comment: Thanks.  That was a waste of several hours for something so simple.  I even iterated over a +/- 500 offset for pos and the item returned was still never nonzero.

Comment: Welcome to SO @jim! If your question is answered please make sure to mark the best answer as accepted by clicking on the check.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use:

```
QPoint tablePoint = table->viewport()->mapFromParent(event->pos()); QModelIndex indexAt = table->indexAt(tablePoint);
QTableWidgetItem *itemAt =table->itemAt(tablePoint);
```

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, I recommend that you also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.